# Why isn't File Explorer immediately affected by Task Scheduler's light/dark mode toggler?

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, automation, windows-task-scheduler, dark-mode

Through Task Scheduler, I set up Windows to automatically switch between Light and Dark Mode. However, although the process works overall--for example, Outlook, Word, Firefox, etc. all seem to work--File Explorer doesn't update when the change triggers. File Explorer does work if I manually force restart File Explorer (through Task Manager, not to be confused with Task Scheduler), but that defeats the purpose of it being automatic. Also, if I manually switch the default app mode from Light to Dark Mode and vice versa, all apps, including File Explorer, work fine--which again defeats the purpose of my automatic tasks.

Why does File Explorer not update when I change the default app mode on Task Scheduler, as opposed to doing so manually? How can I fix it so that File Explorer updates when Task Scheduler toggles the default app color mode? For reference, I have Task Scheduler run `reg` with argument `add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize /v AppsUseLightTheme /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f` for Dark Mode, and for Light Mode the argument is `add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize /v AppsUseLightTheme /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explorer.exe picks up the registry settings when it runs (not all apps do this). If you change it in control panel (personalize settings), the process reloads. Create a batch file with the following and it should work. A line needs to be added to restart explorer.exe.

```
reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize /v AppsUseLightTheme /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe & start explorer
```

The above works going from Light theme to Dark. Point the task in task scheduler at this .bat file or just run it to test. Works for me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way I can configure Task Scheduler to do this without me having to create a batch file? For example, I had Task Scheduler switch to dark mode simply by having it run `reg` with argument `add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize /v AppsUseLightTheme /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f`. Is there a way I could do the same for `taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe & start explorer`? I just tried making a second action for the the task, which runs `reg` again but with the argument `taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe & start explorer`. However, it didn't work.

Comment: No, you need to do the batch. If you have multiple "Actions", task scheduler runs them at the same time. In your case, the registry entry has to be written first, and then explorer needs to be reloaded. If they kick off at the same time, high chance explorer restarts at the same time the registry key is written and it doesnt work. There are workarounds, but the batch is the easiest. The batch file ensures the commands are run in the correct order while waiting for the reg key to be written before the process is reloaded.

Comment: It'd be nice to schedule a task without having to create a new file--just because it seems cleaner to me that way. If I wanted a task that would just restart File Explorer, would the code simply be `taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe & start explorer`? I may have an idea.

Comment: @TheEditor yeah, you could make a second, separate task that runs taskkill.exe and the rest as an argument in theory. But, then you have to fire off two tasks in sequence vs just running one batch file automatically that does it all. Up to you, either should work. Taskkill will probably need to be run as administrator when you set up the task if it works.

Comment: When I tried to create a task to run just `taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe & start explorer`, nothing happened, so I decided to just go with your original suggestion, and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Also, in case others repeat: It might be good to have the task delay if triggering "At log on of any user." Restarting File Explorer immediately at log on can interfere with other programs, so I have mine set to delay for one minute.